# How to access a url from record voicemail in the rest API using Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpq8y.png)A recording is made under incoming call using Twilio Studio and the url can be played within this part of flow using a say widget and this code: {{widgets.record_voicemail_1.RecordingUrl}}. But, when we use this code with with the rest API it won't play the recording. Is there something missing that needs access to in order to play the recording from the rest API?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are using the REST API? Do you mean the Studio Connect Call To Widget and then playing back a recording captured earlier with the Record Voicemail widget or Call Recording widget?

Comment: Yes, its from a recording captured earlier in the same flow but from the incoming call trigger. We want to play the recording in the rest API trigger but the code mentioned above doesn't work.

Comment: Possible to provide a screenshot of your flow (hiding any personal details)?

Comment: The picture is added above in the link

Comment: Since they are different Studio Flows (they have different triggers), they will not have insight into each others flow specific variables, thus {{widgets.record_voicemail_1.RecordingUrl}} is only available in the flow with that widget, "Incoming Call" (Trigger). Maybe you can call the REST API trigger and pass in the URL Encoded Recording URL as a custom parameter, so it has access to it? Reference here, Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API (Customer Parameters): https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API